# Python passing arguments to a function through decorators

Tags: python, architecture

I'm building a class which has a method that takes in a user-defined function to be called within the method. The function can accept arguments from a set of pre-defined arguments which are necessary for the function. The "normal" practice when declaring the function would be to set all arguments as keyword arguments, with a default value of `None`, and just use the arguments that are needed. However, I'm looking for a more elegant solution, which does not explicitly need all arguments listed out.

So I've wrote some decorator functions within the class, which the user can use when declaring the function to notify the class which arguments need to be passed(note that code below are purely examples to show the concept):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.b = None
    
    def use_a(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            kwargs.update({"a": self.a})
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def use_b(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            kwargs.update({"b": self.b})
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def run(self, func):
        for x in range(10):
            self.a = x
            self.b = x * 10
            func()


g = MyClass()

@g.use_a
@g.use_b
def my_custom_function(a, b):
    print(a, b)

myfunc = my_custom_function
g.run(myfunc)
```

The only problem I presume is that the user defined function must be declared after the initialization of the class, which becomes a problem if I want to define the function in another module. So to mitigate this, I decided to create a factory function which accepts an instance as its parameter, and returns the decorated function:

```
# defined in another module
def external_function(instance):
    @instance.use_a
    @instance.use_b
    def custom_func_b(a, b):
        print(a, b)
    return custom_func_b

from mymodule import external_function
g = MyClass()
myfunc = external_function(g)
g.run(myfunc)
```

1. Note that externally defined function get passed its return value, meanwhile functions that are declared within the class initialization scope the function itself is passed. This has a potential to be confusing.
2. As you can see, passing arguments using decorators doesn't seem like an optimal design, since decorators are not recommended to be used in class scopes. I'm wondering if it's worth to continue using this design than accepting all arguments with default values set to `None`, or other methods exist which better suit my case.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have some function that accepts some set of arguments and you'll like to have something that inlines them in your behalf so that you are not required to pass them explicitly every time.

If that's the case, you're kind of reinventing partial function application, which (oversimplifying) boils down to creating a function B that will call function A with some of the arguments of A already passed in. This could be achieved either creating your own implementation of `partial` or using the functools module. In code:

```py
# The base function
def base_function(a, b, c=None):
    print(a, b, c)

# The function that implements partial application
def my_partial(func, *args, **kwargs):
    positional_args = args
    keyword_args = kwargs
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        all_pos_args = positional_args + args
        all_kw_args = {**keyword_args, **kwargs}
        return func(*all_pos_args, **all_kw_args)
    return wrapped

# Usage
new_func = my_partial(base_function, 1, c=3)
new_func(2) # Outputs: 1 2 3

# Now using functools partial
from functools import partial
new_func2 = partial(base_function, 1, c=3)
new_func2(2) # Again: 1 2 3
```

I would generally go ahead with partial instead of more complex solutions for two reasons. The first is that the state of your class decorator hides what would be the result of calling the decorated function which can lead to bugs, also the class must be initialized before decorator usage. The second is that explicitly passing keyword arguments makes the code intent clearer.

As a sidenote decorators that receive arguments also have their place, for instance you may check how the Flask server library implements url routing with the `@app.route("/my/route")` decorator.